# Create a folder with Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, error-handling, swift2, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to use `NSFileManager`'s method `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` in Swift.

The problem is that I have no idea what this function `throws` in case of error. Is this documented *anywhere*? If yes, where?

Comment: You need to handle the error implementing do try catch

Comment: BTW https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Swift docs says a function `throws`, they mean that it throws an `NSError`.

Consider the following `do-try-catch` flow:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(documentsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
    print(error.dynamicType)
}
```

`createDirectoryAtPath` will fail because the documents directory already exists.  Logging the `dynamicType` of the `error` shows that it is in fact an `NSError` object:

> ```
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “Documents” couldn’t be saved in the folder “35B0B3BF-D502-4BA0-A991-D07568AB87C6” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/jal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8A35774-C9B7-42F0-93F1-8103FBBC7118/data/Containers/Data/Application/35B0B3BF-D502-4BA0-A991-D07568AB87C6/Documents, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa88bd14410 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}
>
> NSError
> ```