# How to handle errors with Swift (FileManager and others in general)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

*Note: I posted a lazy question before for converting code to Swift 3 (deleted it)*

Apple has some sample code for managing files. It is an old guide and is all in Objective-C. I converted the snippet to Swift 3. **My concern is over the error handling part.** I'm nesting multiple `do`/`catch` blocks... just want to know if this is the optimal way of doing things??

There is a similar question/amswer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093642/create-a-folder-with-swift).

The document is: [Apple File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH6-SW10), under section "Managing Files and Directories".

This is my code (converted to Swift 3):

```
func backupMyApplicationData() {
        // Get the application's main data directory
        let directories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

        guard directories.count > 0,
            let appSupportDir = directories.first,
            let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else {
            return
        }

        // Build a path to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data
        // where <bundleID> is the actual bundle ID of the application.
        let appDataDir = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent(bundleID).appendingPathComponent("Data")

        // Copy the data to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data.backup
        let backupDir = appDataDir.appendingPathExtension("backup")

        // Perform the copy asynchronously.
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { _ in
            // It's good habit to alloc/init the file manager for move/copy operations,
            // just in case you decide to add a delegate later.
            let fileManager = FileManager()

            do {
                // Just try to copy the directory.
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)

            } catch CocoaError.fileWriteFileExists {
                // If an error occurs, it's probably because a previous backup directory
                // already exists.  Delete the old directory and try again.
                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: backupDir)
                } catch let error {
                    // If the operation failed again, abort for real.
                    print("Operation failed again, abort with error: \(error)")
                }

            } catch let error {
                // If the operation failed again, abort for real.
                print("Other error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is Apple's code in their docs which I converted:

```
- (void)backupMyApplicationData {
   // Get the application's main data directory
   NSArray* theDirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                 inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
   if ([theDirs count] > 0)
   {
      // Build a path to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data
      // where <bundleID> is the actual bundle ID of the application.
      NSURL* appSupportDir = (NSURL*)[theDirs objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
      NSURL* appDataDir = [[appSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID]
                               URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];

      // Copy the data to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data.backup
      NSURL* backupDir = [appDataDir URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"backup"];

      // Perform the copy asynchronously.
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         // It's good habit to alloc/init the file manager for move/copy operations,
         // just in case you decide to add a delegate later.
         NSFileManager* theFM = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
         NSError* anError;

         // Just try to copy the directory.
         if (![theFM copyItemAtURL:appDataDir toURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {
            // If an error occurs, it's probably because a previous backup directory
            // already exists.  Delete the old directory and try again.
            if ([theFM removeItemAtURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {
               // If the operation failed again, abort for real.
               if (![theFM copyItemAtURL:appDataDir toURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {
                  // Report the error....
               }
            }
         }

      });
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: "optimal way" is not really a Stack Overflow question...

Comment: Also, your code does not imitate the behavior of the Objective-C original. Does that matter to you? Isn't that the real aim here, to do the same thing the Objective-C original did? Well, you are not doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to retry the copy operation after deleting an existing backup. Also, "catch let error" can be written as just "catch" because the error will be automatically assigned to a constant named "error" if you don't specify a catch pattern. Here is your code with these changes:

```
func backupMyApplicationData() {
    // Get the application's main data directory
    let directories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    guard
        directories.count > 0,
        let appSupportDir = directories.first,
        let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
    else {
        return
    }

    // Build a path to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data
    // where <bundleID> is the actual bundle ID of the application.
    let appDataDir = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent(bundleID).appendingPathComponent("Data")

    // Copy the data to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data.backup
    let backupDir = appDataDir.appendingPathExtension("backup")

    // Perform the copy asynchronously.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { _ in
        // It's good habit to alloc/init the file manager for move/copy operations,
        // just in case you decide to add a delegate later.
        let fileManager = FileManager()

        do {
            // Just try to copy the directory.
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)                
        } catch CocoaError.fileWriteFileExists {
            // Error occurred because a previous backup directory
            // already exists. Delete the old directory and try again.
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: backupDir)
            } catch {
                // The delete operation failed, abort.
                print("Deletion of existing backup failed. Abort with error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)
            } catch {
                // The copy operation failed again, abort.
                print("Copy operation failed again. Abort with error: \(error)")
            }                
        } catch {
            // The copy operation failed for some other reason, abort.
            print("Copy operation failed for other reason. Abort with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a translation that's closer to the Objective-C original, where there's only one error output, try this:

```
func backupMyApplicationData() {
    // Get the application's main data directory
    let directories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    guard
        directories.count > 0,
        let appSupportDir = directories.first,
        let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
    else {
        return
    }

    // Build a path to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data
    // where <bundleID> is the actual bundle ID of the application.
    let appDataDir = appSupportDir.appendingPathComponent(bundleID).appendingPathComponent("Data")

    // Copy the data to ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_ID>/Data.backup
    let backupDir = appDataDir.appendingPathExtension("backup")

    // Perform the copy asynchronously.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { _ in
        // It's good habit to alloc/init the file manager for move/copy operations,
        // just in case you decide to add a delegate later.
        let fileManager = FileManager()

        // Just try to copy the directory.
        if (try? fileManager.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)) == nil {
            // If an error occurs, it's probably because a previous backup directory
            // already exists.  Delete the old directory and try again.
            if (try? fileManager.removeItem(at: backupDir)) != nil {
                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)
                } catch {
                    // The copy retry failed.
                    print("Failed to backup with error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Showing both ways like this really clarifies things

Answer (score 0):

Your translation of the Objective-C original is incorrect, as has been pointed out in another answer. However, it seems that that is not really your question. It seems that your question is about the nesting.

To answer it, just look at the original that you are trying to imitate:

```
     NSFileManager* theFM = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
     NSError* anError;
     if (![theFM copyItemAtURL:appDataDir toURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {
        if ([theFM removeItemAtURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {
           if (![theFM copyItemAtURL:appDataDir toURL:backupDir error:&anError]) {

           }
        }
     }
```

Notice anything? *Nesting*. So the only difference between the structure of your code and the structure of the original is *what* is nested. The Objective-C original makes a nest of `if` clauses. Your Swift translation makes a nest of do/catch blocks — as it must do, since e.g. Objective-C `copyItemAtURL` returns a BOOL whereas Swift `copyItem(at:)` does not — if there's a problem, it throws.

So I think we may conclude that nesting is *exactly* the right thing to do. Indeed, what's wrong with your code (the reason it isn't an accurate translation of the original) is that it doesn't nest deep enough!

You could try to wrestle at least one of the `catch` blocks out of existence by substituting an `if` block testing what kind of error this is, but you would still be nesting, so why bother? You would just be throwing away all the elegance and clarity of the do/catch construct.

Comment: Good points, thank you.. the answer above really showed me the nesting/error handling as you pointed out as well. Lastly, this doc really cleared things up, [Apple Error Handling Cocoa]https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10. All in all ,my error handling understanding was not great except for basic tasks

Comment: Good, glad you're happier about this.

Comment: @matt, the Objective-C nested if structure can be translated to a Swift nested if structure ( which does not format in a comment :( ):

    let FM = FileManager
    if (try? FM.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)) == nil {
        if (try? FM.removeItem(at: backupDir)) != nil {
            if (try? FM.copyItem(at: appDataDir, to: backupDir)) == nil {

            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Owen yes, I said in my answer that the if structure could be imitated. But the point is that you're still nesting.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 2 and 3, there have 3 way to use a method that may generate errors.

1. If error happened, tell me.

   ```
   do {
       try something()
       try somethingElse()
       print("No error.")
   } catch {
       print("Error:", error)
   }
   ```
2. I don't care about error. If error happen, just return nil.

   ```
   try? something()
   ```
3. I don't believe this will have any error. If error happen, crash my app please.

   ```
   try! something()
   ```

Comment: Right but it looks like from Apples code, they are chaining the `fileManager.removeItem` inside of `fileManager.copyItem`. Apple states the reason in comments, its because `fileManager.copyItem` may file if a file already exists. So what I did is check for that error and call `fileManager.removeItem` inside there. Your code makes sense but not sure if it would accomplish Apple's original intent here